# How to make my app appear in share list in vue native?

Tags: android, vue.js, react-native

I want to know how you can do that in vue native. I want my app to be able to accept images as well as urls and text

[image]

Comment: you can use html share api

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation or example usage?

Comment: here this is called web share api https://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-the-web-share-api/ , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share

Comment: I'm new to vue js. is that a good way to do it?

Comment: the thing is i don't want to trigger the native share dialog i want my app to appear in the native share dialog

Comment: yah you have to custumize it

Comment: watch some youtube video and you'll understand how to use it

Comment: You probably are looking for ```Intent filters``` and/or ```app://schema```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.From the [Link](https://medium.com/swlh/sharing-image-to-android-app-using-intent-filter-to-react-native-d112308328d5)

add these lines to your AndroidManifest file.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

your MainActivity.java

```
package com.sharewithapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "ShareWithApp";
  }

  @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {

            @Override
            protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {

                Intent intent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                if (imageUri != null) {
                    bundle.putString("image", imageUri.toString());
                }else{
                    bundle.putString("image", "");
                }

                return bundle;
            }

        };
    }
}
```

and App.vue file will be

```
<template>
  <view class="container">
    <text class="text-color-primary">My Vue Native App</text>
            <image
          :style="{width: 50, height: 50}"
          :source="{uri: image}"
        />
  </view>
</template>

<style>
.container {
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.text-color-primary {
  color: blue;
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['image']
}
</script>
```

More detail on the link.